# Image seems to look compressed even though it has enough pixels to look good

Tags: css, reactjs, image, styled-components

So I'm trying to embed an image in my react app and I'm struggling with sizing and quality. My image is like 1800x900 pixels and I only need the image to be like 300x150 which makes it reasonable for me to think there will be no problems with its quality. But then I upload my photo to imgbb and place the link in the src attribute and it looks full on blurry on my webpage.

What's weirder is that if I zoom in using my trackpad on my laptop, it regains quality and I see that its not actually blurry. So what am I doing wrong exactly? Is it the way I'm linking my image, the way I'm sizing it?

```
<ProjectImage src="https://i.ibb.co/TRbML9h/financee.jpg" alt="financee" />

const ProjectImage = styled.img `
  width: 290px;
  height: 154px;
  border: 1px solid black;
`
```

Comment: Have a look at [`image-resolution`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/image-resolution) and [`image-rendering`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/image-rendering) CSS properties,I've tried some of them on the image you included but no big difference but they might be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Add `object-fit: contain;` that will adjust image according to parent div or respected image size

More Properties:

```
object-fit: contain;
object-fit: cover;
object-fit: fill;
object-fit: none;
object-fit: scale-down;
```

Comment: Nah that doesnt really do anything, my image is already contained in its container.

Answer (score 0):

It looks normal to me I think, but my 20/20 days are long gone

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-lkkkwk

It is a pretty large image that is being super compressed

Comment: try putting it at 300px, does it look blurry to you? For me it does, even on your fork

Comment: 300px width? It was that already, that leaves only 150px for height. On my two monitors it looks "normal", not really readable but the Financee title, but is because everything  else is so small

Comment: Yeah i dont know I just thought it'd be a little sharper. Like if i open my image in my image viewer and resize it to be roughly the same size as that, it's way sharper. Guess the browser rendering does stuff to it that I dont get